# State Size of Ethereum - why is it so hard to get this number

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, state-trie, state

I am looking for the current state size of Ethereum. Not the size of the data a client downloads when syncing. Just the current state size. It's super hard to get those numbers. Can I somehow run Geth and get the numbers myself?

https://twitter.com/peter_szilagyi/status/1460202014919569410?s=20

[https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/verkle_and_state_expiry_proposal#:~:text=The%20Ethereum%20state%20size%20is,half%20that%20amount%20per%20year](https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/verkle_and_state_expiry_proposal#:%7E:text=The%20Ethereum%20state%20size%20is,half%20that%20amount%20per%20year)

Comment: geth reports the percentage of the synced state so it must _know_ somehow the full size, there's nothing about full size in the `eth_syncing` though